# Why am I getting an error the second time I instantiate a prefab it and every time after that?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnStars : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject circlePrefab;
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Instantiate(circlePrefab);
        }
    }
}
```

It gives me this error:

> UnassignedReferenceException: The variable circlePrefab of SpawnStars
> has not been assigned. You probably need to assign the circlePrefab
> variable of the SpawnStars script in the inspector.
> UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate[T] (T original) (at
> <30adf90198bc4c4b83910c6fb1877998>:0) SpawnStars.Update () (at
> Assets/Assets/Scripts/SpawnStars.cs:13)

the `circlePrefab` variable is assigned in the unity editor. I don't know what to do, please help.

I want it to instantiate the `prefab` without errors.

Comment: are you destroying them at any time?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind I figured it out. turns out that the prefab had the script attached to it so every time I instantiated the prefab it also made the script which resulted in errors.